# facebook oauth redirect outside of the iframe after user confirm application

Tags: php, facebook

Hi guys this one driving me mad for 2 days now!

When I send the user to confirm the application and he/she confirm it, facebook redirect them to my own url (the application url) and breaks the IFRAME by doing so!! 
I tried everything, I also tried to redirect the user to my own script that then redirect the user manually but that failed as well since the user enter the application through "application tab" that located in a facebook page the use my application.

there are sooo many posts about this over the net but i yet to found the solution...
please if anyone can help me it will be great!

Regards,
Moti.

Comment: Can you paste a code example of how you're authorising the users?

Comment: yes, here:$logoutUrl = $facebook -> getLoginUrl();
  echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl  . "'</script>");

Comment: What version of the PHP SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work for you. You would be better off using javascript to handle login and authentication.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId   : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
          session : { VALID_SESSION_DATA }, // don't refetch the session if PHP already has it
          status  : true, // check login status
          cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
        });

      };

      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());

      function login() {
            FB.login(
                function(response) {
                    if (response.session) {
                        if (response.perms) {
                            // user is logged in, and granted any permissions
                        } else {
                           // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
                        }
                    } else {
                        // user is not logged in
                    }
                }, {perms:'publish_stream'}
            );
      }
</script>
```

Comment: yea I know, but you can't redirect the user to the application authorize window without using the "top.location" otherwise you get an error.

Comment: No, I didn't let me try and I tell you how it went.

Comment: Nope still the same result, the redirect destroy the IFrame and open the application in a blank page..

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "Share the link" I'm not at all new to programming but I'm very new to facebook

Comment: I want it to remain inside this facebook page, when you login the second time (after you authorize it) it's OK

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have to play with the code a bit, I will let you know if its did the job.   Many Thanks!